# Do VAs in visual novels usually reprise their roles in anime adaptations?

Tags: anime-production, higurashi-when-they-cry, umineko-when-they-cry, visual-novel-production

Maybe related: [Why do drama CDs and anime series of the same franchise use different voice actors sometimes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/why-do-drama-cds-and-anime-series-of-the-same-franchise-use-different-voice-acto)

---

I notice in WTC / Umineko / Higurashi: Based on [fandom](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Voice_Actors), it seems like for umineko the only difference is [Kasumi Sumadera](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Kasumi_Sumadera). Seems the case for higurashi is similar: the VAs reprise their role from the VN in the anime (or vice-versa in the cases where a VN is released after an anime episode).

I'm not familiar with VNs in general, but afaik, it's not common for, say, live actors to play animated or vice-versa...exceptions include Haruka Fukuhara from Kaguya-sama (Tsubame Koyasu), Riisa Naka from the girl who leapt through time (Akari Yoshiyama & Makoto Konno) or Patton Oswalt (Dementor) from Kim Possible.

But unlike the above case, I guess the idea is that a VN is basically an anime with multiple endings, less animation and more dialogue and so why not just get the same people to reprise the roles?

Comment: Note: this is a repost of [the same question that got deleted automatically by the system](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66644/2516)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [MajinAkuma](https://www.reddit.com/user/MajinAkuma/) in [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/seiyuu/comments/a7sr3h/comment/ia4yl1b/?context=3):

> In the case of Higurashi and Umineko, I‘m sure the anime cast was
> casted first and they reprised their roles for the visual novels. The
> original sound novels had no voice acting, so fans wouldn’t able to
> hear the characters of the first badges until the anime got released.
>
> Same as with Fate/stay night. But in some cases, if later visual
> novels got full voice acting releases on the PS2 editions, then the
> new characters would get their voices for the visual novel first
> before the characters appear in the anime. This happens with many
> other anime adaptations where the original source material didn’t have
> full voice over, like many of the early KEY VNs.
>
> Whether or not a seiyuu doesn’t reprise their role depends on the
> numerous factors, factors we might never know. The Umineko example is
> probably easy to explain. Tanaka Atsuko did voice Kasumi in the anime,
> but Kyrie was her primary role in Umineko. She obviously reprised her
> role as Kyrie in the VNs, but apparently it was unnecessary for her to
> reprise her role as Kyrie‘s sister Kasumi, so they gave her another
> seiyuu to distinguish the sisters better. That might be the right
> choice, since multiple Umineko seiyuus voice multiple versions of the
> same characters or characters that are intended to be copies of each
> other, which is why they have the same voices. Kyrie and Kasumi are
> just sisters, and they don’t disguise themselves as each other like
> the Sonozaki twins from Higurashi.
>
> In Little Busters!, Tamiyasu Tomoe voiced both, Riki and Rin in the
> original visual novel, but in the anime, Riki is voiced by Horie Yui
> instead. Horie probably wasn‘t in the visual novel because Little
> Busters! was original an eroge with H-scenes, and having both
> characters having the same seiyuu in the anime might have been not the
> best idea, so they casted Horie for Riki.
>
> Here’s a funny tidbit. CLANNAD originally came out without voice-over
> like other early KEY titles. The characters wouldn’t get their voices
> until the Toei anime films. The full voice-over version of the visual
> novel would later be released during the run of KyoAni‘s TV series.
> Kuwashima Houko is, of course, the voice of Tomoyo in the Toei films,
> the KyoAni TV series and in the full voice version of CLANNAD.
> However, she didn’t reprise her role for Tomoyo After, which unlike
> CLANNAD, has H-scenes. In Tomoyo After, Tomoyo was voiced by Tanaka
> Ryouko instead. Bur recently in Kaginado, Kuwashima voices both
> versions of Tomoyo: the CLANNAD version and the After version, and the
> anime makes a point to treat both versions as different characters.